# Set div height to 100% of parent

Tags: html, css

I want the following layout for my web page:

```
|         header       |
| navigation | details |
|            |         |
```

Where the navigation pane (content dynamically generated) contains hundreds of elements. I want a vertical scroll bar to be created on the navigation pane such that the pane has the height of the window minus the height of the header.

My page roughly has the following structure:

```
<div id=header></div>
<div id=content>
  <div id=navigation></div>
  <div id=details></div>
</div>
```

With the following CSS:

```
#navigation {
    float: left;
    width: 400px;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}

#details {
    margin-left: 420px;
}
```

This mostly works except that the navigation pane gets 100% of the height of the window, not 100% of the height of the window minus the height of the header. I'd rather not explicitly set the height of the header if I can avoid it. I am completely new to web development so I don't mind doing some reading. What do I need to do to achieve the layout that I want?

Comment: Try use `overflow:scroll` for navigator. Also, do you see the header at all or content take up its space too?

Comment: overflow:scroll gives the same effect. I can see the header, but the scroll bar appears to be the height of the entire window, not the height of just the navigation div.

Comment: I've try number of different setting and can't seems to help you. Perhaps, this is one of the case where table is better suited. Just a thought.

Comment: I'm curious, what is your reasoning for not wanting to give the header a height?

Comment: Can you recreate your problem with a simple jsfiddle (or equiv.)?

Answer (score 1):

You must ensure your body tag and content container also have heights of 100%.  You must explicitly set the height of the parent element(s) for the child to obey.

```
body { 
    height: 100%;
} 

#content {
    height: 100%;
}
```

This does not, however, take into consideration positioning of the header.  The following post demonstrates a technique utilizing the min-height fast hack by Dustin Diaz and a negative margin on the content container to achieve 100% height while not interfering with the header:

http://www.thechoppr.com/blog/2009/02/08/3-column-fluid-layout-100-height/

Comment: Setting the height of the body and content elements doesn't seem to help. What do you mean by "it does not take into consideration the positioning of the header"?

Answer (score 1):

You said "I'd rather not explicitly set the height of the header *if I can avoid it*."  I'm pretty sure you can't avoid it without switching to tables. That said, here is an example of how you can do it using divs with the header's height set to 50px:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            html, body {
                margin:0;
            }

            div#content {
                position:absolute;
                top:0px;
                z-index:-1;
                width:100%;
            }

            html, body, div#content, div#navigation-shell, div#details-shell {
                height:100%;
            }

            div#header {
                height:50px;
            }

            div#navigation-shell {
                float:left;
                width:400px;
            }

            div#navigation, div#details{
                padding-top:50px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header"></div>
        <div id="content">
            <div id="navigation-shell">
                <div id="navigation"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="details-shell">                
                <div id="details"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**One note:**  If you want to add backgrounds to the `navigation` and/or `details` areas, you will have to actually apply those to the their respective shell divs that encase them.  All actual content, however, would go in the inner divs.

Comment: I said that I'd rather not set the height of the header because I don't want to have to know it. My current page header is just some 50pt text, but I might replace this with a graphic later on. I was hoping that I wouldn't need to modify the height/padding property of the navigation div every time I change the header.

Comment: I can understand that.  However, a fixed height will help to keep a consistent page layout across all browsers.  It may be kind of a pain to change the header's height when you change its content, but once you settle on a header you like, you won't have to worry about it anymore.  This is all of course up to you, but I'm fairly certain that an auto-sizing header div with 2 full-screen divs below is impossible without the bug.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set BOTH html and body height to 100%: `html, body {height: 100%;}`